# Design of microstrip tranmission line

Tags: microstrip, quadrature

this might sound silly but I am a little confused as to how the quadrature coupler relates to the microstrip transmission line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'The' quadrature coupler does not relate to microstrip transmission line.

If you bring a second transmission line 'close' to a first, so that some field is shared, then you get two coupled transmission lines.

You can do this with any sort of transmission line, stripline, microstrip, co-planar or slot-line. You can even use coaxial or waveguide for appropriate definitions of 'close' (ie that they share field, holes in the outer are involved).

If you make the coupled section the right length, and with the right amount of coupling, then you get a quadrature coupler.

Generally microstrip's non-homogeneous dielectric (part air, part plastic) means it does not make good couplers, stripline with its homogeneous dielectric is better. The economy of microstrip and its ease of integration means it is still used for couplers, especially where low performance is permissible. If you see a microstrip coupler with 'crocodile teeth' on  the facing edges, this is where it's been modified to equalise the even and odd phase velocities caused by the non-homogeneous dielectric, to improve the coupler performance.

You can also make couplers using a network of connected transmission lines, rather than the 'field coupled' types discussed above.